# how much of data usage a http post request?

Tags: android, http-post, high-traffic

I am writing an application for android and in the app i use some `HttpPost` requests. 
i have a service in which i schedule 3 request at constant times.
one every 1.5 seconds, one every 7 seconds and one every 20 seconds.
most of times web service don't return any thing.

i install my app on a device and check it for 2 days. this app use 40M data although `viber` use only 4M . (i found it by check data usage part at device settings.)

how much data use by a simple `HttpPost` request?

how i can reduce data usage in my app ?

Comment: Almost nothing... You should look the content (params) that you send, maybe you can optimize that ?

Comment: are you able to do work on the server ?

Comment: I can not send any thing to a device. For example you assume that this app is a chat application so I should check every 1.5 seconds to found that this user have @@y message or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the only person able to find out how much any POST request costs is you. It depends a lot on the headers/data you send.

HTTP introduces some overhead in the data sent. For example, using cURL to post just a pair of values p1=v1 and p2=v2, those are the headers sent:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Those are just the headers (the body adds 11 bytes to this). As you can guess, doing this every 1.5 seconds creates a lot of traffic.

To reduce this, you can do some things:

- Lower the rate of requests to the server. Do you really need to post every 1,5 seconds?
- If you post a lot of data, check if HttpPost lets you compress the data you send / the server supports HTTP compression;
- Consider the usage of other technologies like plain sockets/websockets. If the data you post is small this will help by reducing the overhead of HTTP.

**EDIT:** I am assuming you are using POST requests to really post data to the server. If you are using it to get some kind of state from the server, something like (Web)sockets or using push notifications can reduce a lot the requests required.

Comment: I explain my idea to use httpPost every 1.5 seconds at a comment below my question. You can assume that this is a chat application and I should check every 1.5 seconds to found that user have any new message or not and if have messages webserver will return them as request response.

Comment: If you have control of the server, as I said something like Websockets or server sent events should work a lot better than this. This allows you to avoid much of the overhead imposed by HTTP and also will give you the possibility of communication from server to the device (so there is no need to check every 1.5 secons if there a re new messages: when you have a new message, you can just send it ot the right device)

Comment: If you don't control the server, then you will have to optimize what you can. But note that you should always be able to add a second server, controlled by you between your mobile apps and the current server, and use whatever technology you need there.

Comment: I don't know how can server communicate with device where device does not have valid ip? Is there q package or so that help me to achieve this?

Comment: Device opens the connection and keep it open. Then both server and client can read/write to it.

Comment: How can I find tutorial for this? I mean what name is perfect for search and find about this method?

Comment: Don't forget about old-fashioned long-polling as a solution, too.